# Insert link to a heading with ID

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Running Doom Emacs 2.0.9 on Emacs 27.1.

In an org file, I have:

```
* First heading
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       89f7215b-60b1-45c8-8262-b0e10db18f4c
  :END:
* Second heading
```

I got that ID by using `org-id-store-link` function.

Now, I want to insert a link to that heading. So, I did `org-insert-link` and it displayed various options. I was looking forward to some kind of auto-completion --- I start typing Firs.. and it suggests the correct link.

But that does not seem to be happening.

How do I get that behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enable ID links by customizing the option `org-id-link-to-org-use-id`. The doc string of the variable says:

> Non-nil means storing a link to an Org file will use entry IDs.
>
> The variable can have the following values:
>
> t
>
> ```
>  Create an ID if needed to make a link to the current entry.
> ```
>
> create-if-interactive
>
> ```
>  If ‘org-store-link’ is called directly (interactively, as a user
>  command), do create an ID to support the link.  But when doing the
>  job for capture, only use the ID if it already exists.  The
>  purpose of this setting is to avoid proliferation of unwanted
>  IDs, just because you happen to be in an Org file when you
>  call ‘org-capture’ that automatically and preemptively creates a
>  link.  If you do want to get an ID link in a capture template to
>  an entry not having an ID, create it first by explicitly creating
>  a link to it, using ‘C-c l’ first.
> ```
>
> create-if-interactive-and-no-custom-id
>
> ```
>  Like create-if-interactive, but do not create an ID if there is
>  a CUSTOM_ID property defined in the entry.
> ```
>
> use-existing
>
> ```
>  Use existing ID, do not create one.
> ```
>
> nil
>
> ```
> Never use an ID to make a link, instead link using a text search for
>  the headline text.
> ```

I'd start by setting it to `use-existing` and go from there.

Comment: Thanks. I did set up the variable as suggested. `(setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id 'use-existing)`. Now when I try to create link `org-insert-link`, it shows me various options like doom-repo, wolfram, wikipedia, etc. In this list of 35 items, there is an option for id and another option for org. Selecting org, I can create a link to an org file. But how do I create a link to a heading? Do I need to use any other commands?

Comment: With the option on, you should be able to `org-store-link` (suggested binding: `C-c l`) on a heading with an ID property and then `org-insert-link` (suggested binding: `C-c C-l`) to insert such a link.

Comment: Thanks. With `org-store-link` it works even without the ID property set. So, why does one go the extra mile to create an ID? 

By the way, this led me to reading the manual about links and that led me to discover a couple of very powerful things. :)

Comment: Basically IDs are (spposed to be) unique, so the link desitnation is unambiguous.

Comment: Where are the links stored and how could one remove them?

Comment: The *links* are stored in whatever file you were visiting when you did `org-store-link`. If you are talking about the ID database (i.e. in which file the ID is defined), that is stored in the file that is named by the variable `org-id-locations-file`. Do `C-h v` on that variable for more info.

Comment: "he links are stored in whatever file you were visiting when you did org-store-link" @NickD, how to remove them?

Comment: Delete them? But I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing. In any case, comments on a different answer are not the best way to proceed. You should formulate a detailed question and ask it separately.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `org-insert-link`, *not* `org-store-link`. The comment above should read: 
"The *links* are stored in whatever file you were visiting when you did `org-insert-link` ..."